# Rails custom action missing required key error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @script.Name %></h1>

<%= simple_form_for @script , :url => script_execute_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :mainDirectory %>
  <%= f.input :customFilePath %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Run' %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
  root :to => "scripts#index"
  resources :scripts do
    get "execute"
  end
```

Model

```
class AddNameToScript < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :scripts, :Name, :string
    add_column :scripts, :Description, :text
  end
end
```

`execute` is a custom action added by me and I want to goto that action from `show`.

routes.rb

```
...
    script_execute GET    /scripts/:script_id/execute(.:format) scripts#execute
...
```

But I am getting an error

```
No route matches {:action=>"execute", :controller=>"scripts", :id=>"1"} 
missing required keys: [:script_id]
```

But why do I need a `[:script_id]`? Isn't it a custom action and I can define the way I want? What's missing here and how do I pass `[:script_id]`?

Comment: Can you please add the output of this command – `rake routes | grep execute` – to your question? This will show what parameters, if any, the `execute` method is expecting.

Comment: @jeffdill2: Now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from your router output, `execute` *is* expecting a `script_id` parameter (`/scripts/:script_id/execute(.:format`). To remove that expectation, you need to declare that route at the `collection` instead of `member` level. You can do this in one of two ways:

```
get :execute, on: :collection
```

Or if you have other routes that you want to include on the collection, you can throw it in a block:

```
collection do
  get :execute
end
```

FYI, after this change run `rake routes | grep execute` again to see what the name of the URL helper has changed to so you can update your view accordingly.

Cheers!

---

#### UPDATE:

To answer the question in the comments, if you wanted to pass in a `script_id` parameter (or any parameter for that matter), you can do so by declaring it as a parameter to the URL helper. So based on your current view, it would look like this:

```
<h1><%= @script.Name %></h1>

<%= simple_form_for @script , :url => script_execute_path(script_id: @script.id) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :mainDirectory %>
  <%= f.input :customFilePath %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Run' %>
<% end %>
```

However, I would like to point out a couple more things here:

1. It appears that you're intending to update a `Script` object, so I'm not sure why you're creating the `execute` method from a `show` view, instead of just using the `update` method that's already available via `resources :scripts` from an `edit` view.
2. Again, it appears that you're intending to PUT or POST something based on your view, but your `execute` route is defined as a GET. Not sure if that's what you intend.

Comment: What if I need /scripts/:script_id/execute(.:format) format then how do I pass the id?

Comment: @InQusitive one sec, I'll update my answer to address your question.

Comment: sad that there is no double 'like' option :)

Comment: Ha! I recommend checking out these docs – http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. You'll be a routing pro in no time. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Pass `:id` to your form helper and try

```
<%= simple_form_for @script , :url => script_execute_path(@script) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :mainDirectory %>
  <%= f.input :customFilePath %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Run' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is going to pass `id`.